# Selecionar numero de linhas retornadas

Tags: postgresql

É possível selecionar o número de linhas retornadas em um select? 
Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso teria que ser retornado 12.

Comment: vc quer só o count mesmo como a giuliana postou ?

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível através da função *count*. A sintaxe é da seguinte forma:

```
select count(*) from tabela where condição;
```

O *count* também pode ser usado em conjunto com outras funções para realizar uma contagem de linhas mais flexível (e.g. count + group by).